# Is it allowed selling a kvm virtual machine with Ubuntu? what about copyright?

Tags: copyright

I would like know if it is allowed creating a package with a KVM virtual machine + Ubuntu as OS and sell this package. Is there any restriction due to copyright or fees to pay?

I would not modify anything on the KVM or Ubuntu, just add my scripts on Ubuntu for the customers.

KVM's parts are licensed under various GNU licenses:

- KVM kernel module: GPL v2
- KVM user module: LGPL v2
- QEMU virtual CPU core library (libqemu.a) and QEMU PC system emulator: LGPL
- Linux user mode QEMU emulator: GPL
- BIOS files (bios.bin, vgabios.bin and vgabios-cirrus.bin): LGPL v2 or later

Any idea?
Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the licenses of the software included in your machine/package. If you manage to weed out everything that is not GPL (except for *your* scripts of course) then [yes](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html).

Otherwise you have to go through every piece of software you include and check what the licenses say.

Comment: I would use KVM and Ubuntu as it is, just adding to the UBUNTU the following packages: Java, Firefox broswer. I'm worried mostly for KVM (see first post).

Comment: @user3472065 KVM is the least of your problems as it is all GPL/LGPL. I would be more concerned about stuff like [restricted extras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu-restricted-extras).

Comment: great! since I will use Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS default installation, I think I'm safe :)